# Magento2 - adminhtml_customer not showing in Forms to Use In

Tags: magento2, customer, adminhtml, customer-attribute

I have programatically created a customer attribute and set it to be displayed in **adminhtml_customer**. All is good, the attribute is being displayed only in the admin customer edit section as desired.

```
$attributeCode = 'attribute_code';

$eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode,
    [
        'type'          => 'varchar',
        'label'         => 'Attribute Lable',
        'input'         => 'multiselect',
        'backend'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend::class,
        'global'        => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'source'        => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class,
        'visible'       => true,
        'user_defined'  => true,
        'system'        => false,
        'required'      => false,
        'unique'        => false,
        'position'      => 200
    ]
);

$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode);

$attribute
    ->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer'])
    ->save();
```

However, when I try to edit the attribute in the M2 admin (Store/Attributes/Customer) - let's say I want to make it show in another area, the adminhtml_customer option is not available for selection in the *Forms to Use In* list (adminhtml_customer_address is not available either).

[image]

Looking through the code I found the following:

\Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Helper\Customer::getAttributeFormOptions

```
/**
 * Return available customer attribute form as select options
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAttributeFormOptions()
{
    return [
        ['label' => __('Customer Registration'), 'value' => 'customer_account_create'],
        ['label' => __('Customer Account Edit'), 'value' => 'customer_account_edit'],
        ['label' => __('Admin Checkout'), 'value' => 'adminhtml_checkout']
    ];
}
```

Since adminhtml_customer and adminhtml_customer_edit are M2 out of the box options you would expect to find those in the list, right?

Any thoughts?

Later edit:
Customer Attributes are only available on M2 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Just checked M2 Commerce 2.2.9 (Enterprise), the `\Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Helper\Customer::getAttributeFormOptions` method is the same. Also it looks like adding/removing `adminhtml_customer` to `used_in_forms` has no effect, the field is displayed anyway in the customer edit form in the backend. Also 'visible' (which is actually transformed into `is_visible` by the mapper) has no effect on the backend customer edit form, field is visible regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your attribute in `adminhtml_customer_address`

you have to create a customer address attribute. In this case your install data becomes like this

```
    $attributeCode = 'attribute_code';

$eavSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode,
    [
        'type'          => 'varchar',
        'label'         => 'Attribute Lable',
        'input'         => 'multiselect',
        'backend'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend::class,
        'global'        => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'source'        => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class,
        'visible'       => true,
        'user_defined'  => true,
        'system'        => false,
        'required'      => false,
        'unique'        => false,
        'position'      => 200
    ]
);

$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);

$attribute
    ->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer_address'])
    ->save();
```

In this way you will see your attribute in adminhtml customer address form but not in adminhtml customer form, because customer and customer_address are separated entities.

Comment: the question is about adminhtml_customer

Comment: I explained why adminhtml_customer_address is not available

Comment: the question is also about why the two adminhtml options are not being displayed in the Forms to Use In list - thanks for your answer, but it is not on topic

Comment: They are not displayed because you created a customer attribute. Those options are displayed only for customer address attributes. Anyway if you think this is not the point maybe I have not understood what it is! :)

Comment: I have tried to create an address attribute. The only two options in the [Forms to Use In] when adding a Customer Address attribute are [Customer address registration] and [Customer Account Registration]